# query regarding sprintf() and scanf()

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Take for example

```
int i=10,j;

float b=3.14,c;

char str[30];

sprintf(str,"%d%f",i,b);

sscanf(str,"%d%f",&j,&c);

printf("%d  -----  %f\n",j,c);
```

> #### OUTPUT :- 103 ----- 0.1400000

As you can see, initially `i=10` and `b=3.14`.

I want that `j=10` and `c=3.14`  by using `sprint()` and `sscanf()`.

The problem I am facing is that the compiler assigns `j=103` and `c=0.140000`.

Is there any way to get rid of this problem in `sscanf()`?

Comment: Add one space: change `sprintf(str,"%d%f",i,b)` to `sprintf(str,"%d %f",i,b)`.

Comment: Alternative: Print `b` with its sign `sprintf(str,"%d%+f",i,b);`.  The sign will act as a delimiter when scanning back.  (Adding the space though is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one space to `sprintf`. Change:

```
sprintf(str,"%d%f",i,b)
```

to

```
sprintf(str,"%d %f",i,b)
```

Aside: It would be also safer to use `snprintf` here:

```
snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%d %f", i, b)
```

Comment: what that space is actually doing

Comment: you mean to say that it separates the values

Comment: It acts as a delimiter to the inputs.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey : After adding space to `sprintf()`, do I also need to put space between `sscanf()`

Comment: Quick answer, no. Longer answer: Most of the format specifiers (with the notorious exemption of `%c`) automatically skip over white space. But one often sees unnecessary spaces: for example, `%s %s` is exactly the same as `%s%s`.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey : In this particular case, there is no need because `%d` and `%f` both deal with numbers, in case of `%c` I think that I will need `space` in `sscanf()` also

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to separate the numbers, using a different sign, but if you know that the first int is 2 chars long you can specify it:

```
sscanf(str,"%2d%f",&j,&c);
//           ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space

Change

```
sprintf(str,"%d%f",i,b);
```

to

```
sprintf(str,"%d %f",i,b);

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=10,j;

    float b=3.14,c;

    char str[30];

    sprintf(str,"%d %f",i,b);

    sscanf(str,"%d%f",&j,&c);

    printf("%d  -----  %f\n",j,c);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
~ > ./a.out
10  -----  3.140000
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` conversion specifier in `sscanf` will match any number of contiguous numeric characters in the buffer pointed to by `str` till it encounters a non-numeric character which it can't match. This will cause the integral part of the float to be read as part of the int value. Therefore you must have a way to separate where you integer ends and float starts in the string `str`. You can put any non-numeric character as a sentinel to separate int value from the float value.

```
int i = 10, j;
float b = 3.14, c;
char str[30];

// a # to separate the two values, can be any non-numeric char so that it
// is not mistaken for a digit in the int or float value

sprintf(str,"%d#%f", i, b);  

// match the separator character to read int and then float

sscanf(str, "%d#%f", &j, &c);
```